# How do I replace zeroes in multiple variable dataframes within a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, replace, eval, assign

So I have 1,000 dataframes to process using a FOR loop in R, say they are named DF1 to DF1000. I need to replace all 0 values within the data frames to 1's.  I try to write this as follows.

```
for (i in 1:1000){
eval(as.symbol(paste0("DF","i")))[eval(as.symbol(paste0("DF","i")))==0]<-1
}
```

This brings up an error ("could not find eval<-").  How do I resolve this issue?  I tried using "assign" but get a different error ("target of assignment expands to non-language object").

Thanks in advance,
Alvo

Comment: Best thing to do is to put all the data frames into a `list`, then `lapply(list, function(x) replace(x, x == 0, 1))`

Comment: thanks @Rich Scriven. One question though.  Say if this was just the first of 10 or 20 things I'm doing to these 1000 dataframes.  Does that mean I would have to do this before the other 19 things, outside the For loop?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to `assign` every character value `DF` to a new `DF` in the global environment, using base `replace` function.

```
for (i in 1:1000){
      assign(paste0("DF", i),
             replace(eval(parse(text = paste0("DF", i))), eval(parse(text = paste0("DF", i))) == 0, 1),
             envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }
```

This is similar to `replace(DF,DF == 0, 1)` outside the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks @HNSKD.  I quite like this method as I can do it within the same loop.  Could the person who downvoted this explain why it shouldn't be used?